# magento product view design file

Tags: magento, templates, view, product

Looking for the template which controlling the design of the product view in Magenti 1.7

is it catalog.xml ??

or there is some other phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

The xml files define what phtml files make up your templates. You are looking for a phtml file something like product/view.phtml. Here are some guides on how to create your own theme: http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide if you are going to be working with magento a lot it is definitely worth reading these

Comment: Thank you Barrett
Actually I have installed an extension called Daily Deal, but I dont know how to add the daily deal to the home page :(, looking to have some idea from the default product view to design the home page.

Comment: @aansari, you can specify what page you want to be your home page in the admin panel. Just set it to a daily deal page. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-change-the-home-page